# Geodata of Great Wall of China

Tags: geospatial, china

Where can I get a freely usable geo dataset of the Great Wall of China? I would prefer a (Multi-)LineString, not something with an area but any format is ok. Vector data in any format, as long as I can somehow get it into GDAL/OGR or similar free software tools.

The only datasets I found are not publicly available and under very restrictive licenses.

OpenStreetMap has a relation (https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/318110 (warning, huge)) but it is disconnected and incomplete.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want this in, shapefile, x/y coordinates of the path?

Comment: I would take any format, prefering something vector but would even take a raster set if the resolution is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [website](https://confluence.cc.lehigh.edu/display/~tch207/Geospatial+Social+Studies) which links to a project related to the Wall and a few resources in kmz format.
I haven't had a look at the actual data though.

There should also be a dataset [here](https://confluence.cc.lehigh.edu/download/attachments/6489105/Great+Wall+of+China.kmz), according to [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_maps_exist_of_the_Great_Wall_of_China_as_KML_files_for_opening_via_Google_Earth).

Comment: This website URL should persist a little longer hopefully and you can download the latest versions from here: https://confluence.cc.lehigh.edu/display/~tch207/Geospatial+Social+Studies