# Shapefiles of the Great Wall of China and the Silk Road

Tags: geospatial, historical, geocoding, china

I am looking for shapefiles of two Chinese landmarks.

1. Great Wall of China. Format: spatial lines. The sources mentioned in another [post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12149/21916) are apparently not available anymore.
2. Silk Road. Format: spatial lines, points or polygons.

Comments on maps that can be geocoded are also welcome.

Comment: Have you searched on this web-site http://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/

Comment: Yes. And there is only this inadequate shapefile: http://worldmap.harvard.edu/maps/13529/info/.

Comment: Actually, I did find data on the Silk Road. But I still need a shapefile on the Great Wall of China.

Comment: Chr, could you please help me to find Silk Road GISdata as well. Thank you advance!)

Comment: http://worldmap.harvard.edu/maps/7547/info/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Overpass API to get data in GeoJSON format.
You can query using WikidataID parameter (Q12501)

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON

Example on https://geoattractions.com/details/55971

[image]

Comment: For that to work the Great Wall of China needs to be a feature in OpenStreetMap, right? However, OpenStreetMap only covers tiny isolated pieces.

Comment: But all these features have same Wikidata ID. Check map using OSM data on this page
https://geoattractions.com/details/55971

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled upon this thread on my search for a historic Silk Road GPX track, I will leave my finding here for others who might find it useful.

I found [this website](https://on-historic-routes.com/featured-routes/historic-silk-road/), that displays [this GPX-Track](https://on-historic-routes.com/loglog/wp-content/uploads/00%20-%20Silk%20Road%20Network_001.gpx), as can be found in the network communication dev tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I used this query on https://overpass-turbo.eu/ to get a KML of all features related to the Great Wall of China from OpenStreetMap (hit the "Run" button to run the query, then go to "Export" > "KML")

```
[out:json];
rel(318110);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

NB: 318110 is the Great Wall of China's OpenStreetMap relation ID.

This link should load the query directly: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1FyX